# Alternative for Facebook chat API (followup)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-chat

This is in followup to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23767227/alternative-for-facebook-chat-api). I noticed recently that a new /{user-id}/inbox endpoint has been added to the graph API. Also some new classes like Thread and Message can be seen in the docs. Is this officially the new replacement?

Comment: No that existed since API v1.0 . /{user-id}/inbox requires read_mailbox which is only approved for what is listed on: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.1#reference-read_mailbox . So your app will most likely not get approved for it

Comment: Uh oh.. Hadn't noticed that before... So, there is no replacement yet? A bit strange since we've got little more than half a year before it is dunzo...

Comment: If the idea was to have a replacement it would have been there from day 1. Because every single app created after 4/30/2014 can't use the old chat api and haven't been able to for the last 6 months.